# Input field within absolutely-positioned div breaks layout in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a div as a "dialog box" on a web page. I've defined it as follows:

```
#ha2game {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:50%;
    width:258px; height:258px;
    margin-top:110px;
    margin-left:-155px;
    padding:21px;
    background-color:#900;
    border:1px #444 solid;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    display:none;
    z-index:100;
}

    #gamename {
        border:1px solid #444;
        margin:15px 4% 0 4%;
        width:90%;  
        font-size:40px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        font-weight:bold; }
```

It appears when the user clicks on a button I've hooked a jQuery show() up to. In Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, the behavior works as expected, the div overlays all the html elements below it. In IE 7, however, the dialog breaks the page layout. I am 99% sure it is the `<input>` tag within the div that is affecting the flow of the content "below" the dialog div.

Let me know if anything stands out about the way I've defined the div style.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>stackoverflow</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cfg/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/mad4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="stage">
    <!-- GAME SCENE -->
    <div class="stage_inner" id="scene_game"> 
        <div class="common_inner">
            <img class="homelink" src="img/mad4logo300x100.png" width="300" height="100" alt="film school" />
        </div>
        <div class="game_inner" id="filter">
            <img src="img/characterslabel.png" width="130" height="29" />
            <img class="imglink" id="showall" src="img/recycle.png" width="30" height="30"/><img class="imglink" id="charslide" src="img/downarrow.png" width="30" height="30"/>
            <br />
            <hr style="width:100%; margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:17px; color:#EEE" />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="game_inner" id="ha2script"> 
            <img src="img/screenplaylabel.png" width="130" height="29" /><br /><hr style="width:100%; margin-top:-14px; margin-bottom:25px; color:#EEE;" />
        </div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- GAME -->
<div id="ha2game">
  <div id="ha2game_hd">
        <span id="s1_hd"><div class="allstagewhite">Enter your name for history...</div></span>
    </div>
    <div id="ha2game_bd">
        <span id="s1_bd"><input autocomplete="none" id="gamename" type="text" size="8" maxlength="7" value=""></input></span>
    </div>
    <div id="ha2game_ft">
        <span id="s1_ft"><div class="allstagewhite">START!</div></span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm just doing a `$('#ha2game').show()`.

Comment: This could be the IE Z-index bug, but without all of your code it's hard to tell.

Comment: Also what mode is the page being rendered in: quirks or standard?

Comment: @Diodeus, agree that we need more code. The `z-index` bug does not disrupt the flow, it just does not recognize the `z-index`.

Comment: @Steve M... can you please post the HTML and ideally the Jquery as well. Your CSS seems fine.

Comment: That should be `$('#ha2game').show()`. please add the relevant css to http://www.jsfiddle.net/U7YwT/

Comment: Sorry, i omitted the #. After narrowing this problem down with commenting the HTML...it looks like that input tag within #s1_bd is messing up the content flow.

Comment: Ok, so I actually got this thing working through an absurd hack. I set the margin-left on the input element to 496 (not 495, that still broke it). I think it has something to do with the hasLayout property. The input element apparently inherited the margins from the ancestor elements, so to offset it you give it some margin it needs. `<shrug>`

Answer (score 0):

Try just initially setting `left:-999em` in the CSS, and instead of `.show()` do `.css('left', '50%')`.

If that doesnt work, can you post relevant html surrounding this? And maybe try to wrap a div around this element, basically create a wrapper around it but dont apply any styles to the wrapper.

Comment: i posted the page's html. the problem isn't with the show() function but with the input tag within the "dialog" div. i will update my original question. thanks for your help.